# Knockoutjs: some observables binding but not visible in Safari

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, safari, observable

I have a Knockout view-model which is displayed correctly in all browsers on Windows and Mac... except Safari on the Mac.

Here is the HTML with the data-binding attributes:

```
<div data-bind="visible: !Loading(), with: SelectedAddress">
    <!-- ko if: Comment().length -->
        <span data-bind="text: Comment"></span><br/>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: Company().length -->
        <span data-bind="text: Company"></span><br/>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: Name().length -->
        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span><br/>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: Address1().length -->
        <span data-bind="text: Address1"></span><br/>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: Address2().length -->
        <span data-bind="text: Address2"></span><br/>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: ZipAndCity().length -->
        <span data-bind="text: ZipAndCity"></span><br/>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: CountryName().length -->
        <span data-bind="text: CountryName"></span><br/>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

The strange problem is that the first two bound fields, for `Comment` and `Company`, do not show their text on Safari. However, there are spaces for them - you can see that there shouldn't be a line break if there is no content in the field, and the line breaks for both those fields *are* showing up.

Furthermore, Safari's Developer Tools reveals that the DOM elements *have* been populated with the expected text.

And even more: if you click and highlight the text, then it becomes visible. The same is true if Safari is dragged to another screen. In other words, if Safari has to re-paint then the text is rendered, but when the Knockout binding is applied, although the text is added to the DOM element, it is *not* rendered.

I have also tried using virtual elements / containerless binding like so

```
<!-- ko if: Comment().length -->
    <!-- ko text: Comment --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- /ko -->
```

but this has no effect on the outcome.

I tried putting together a jsfiddle example, but it worked. So this might have something to do with the interplay of all the observables on the page, or the nesting of the view-models, *etc*.

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong, or any workarounds?

**UPDATE:**

The problem appears to have been related to the `visible: !Loading()` binding on the parent `<div>`.

If I remove this then the problem goes away.

I know that this doesn't exactly *solve* the problem, but for me it removes the problem as that particular binding was no longer needed anyway.

I also found that if I moved those two problematic fields, `Comment` and `Company`, to the end of the list then the next two fields, `Name` and `Address1`, inherited the problem. However, if I removed two fields then the problem went away.

Comment: sounds like a bug in safari to me, might want to push it through their support systems

Comment: Are you suggesting that Apple have a bug reporting mechanism where they welcome and happily investigate user submissions?

Comment: Dunno about welcoming and happy, but try [here](http://www.apple.com/au/support/mac-apps/safari/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a browser issue on re-flow the inner content.

Could you try this to force knockout to regenerate the whole DOM when loading finished?

```
<!-- ko ifnot: Loading -->
    <div data-bind="with: SelectedAddress">
        <!-- ko if: Comment().length -->
            <span data-bind="text: Comment"></span><br/>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: Company().length -->
            <span data-bind="text: Company"></span><br/>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: Name().length -->
            <span data-bind="text: Name"></span><br/>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: Address1().length -->
            <span data-bind="text: Address1"></span><br/>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: Address2().length -->
            <span data-bind="text: Address2"></span><br/>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: ZipAndCity().length -->
            <span data-bind="text: ZipAndCity"></span><br/>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: CountryName().length -->
            <span data-bind="text: CountryName"></span><br/>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @huocp, but that makes no difference. I pasted your suggestion in, loaded the page, but I'm still left with blank spaces.